# php weird issue when calling from web browser

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing a video game, and experimenting a weird behavior trying to get the `MAX` value of a table in my database.

```
"select MAX(challengeID) AS challengeID from Challenges"
```

When I execute the sentence from phpMyAdmin all is going as expected, but when I call it from a web browser, I have to query twice in order to get the right answer. First time I call it from browser is returning the last MAX value before updating the table... maybe something related to cache¿

Edit:
There is all the PHP code (I think it is not a code issue, since it is the easiest query in the project...)

PHP code:

```
<?php 

 # connection stuff

 $query = "select MAX(challengeID) AS challengeID from Challenges"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' .mysql_error()); 

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 echo  $row['challengeID'];
?>
```

More info: I also tried this query with exactly the same issue

```
select challengeID from challenges group by challengeID order by challengeID desc
```

Thanks!
Carlos

Comment: Maybe you show us php code? Or we should imagine it?

Comment: SQL doesn't execute from the browser, so we need more context to help you. Show us how your front end makes a call to your PHP, and how your PHP makes the query and responds.

Comment: `First time I call it from browser is returning the last MAX value before updating the table`? it's unclear what you want to say. also show your php code

Comment: Anant, there is the procedure:

table example:

ChallengeID
1
2
3
4
--->
select Max returns 4
--->

I update the table, from phpmyadmin or from php code (add a 5)--->

run the php code from browser-->
returns 4--->

run again the php code from browser--->
returns 5

Comment: @BeetleJuice  I skipped my real front end to discard it as guilty, and experimenting the same issue just copying the url of the php code www.mypage.com/GetLastChallengeID.php? , this url triggers the code posted at the update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got the solution. Adding a hash code to the url is returning the correct value at the first call. The hash has to be different from the last hash used, but every two calls it is reseted  ( I dont know why... I have to open a new question¿ ).

Thanks for your help! And @u_mulder take a tea please :)